# Ambiguous overload of std::vector::operator[]

Tags: c++

I have a simple wrapper around C null-terminated string, which is essentially a subclass of std::vector< char >. (Yes, I know about std::string, but my wrapper is easier to cooperate with C functions expecting char*. Also, std::string isn't guaranteed to be contiguous in C++03)

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<char> vector_char;
class c_string : public vector_char
{
    public:
    c_string(size_t size) : vector_char(size+1) {}

    c_string(const char* str)
    {
        if(!str) return;
        const char* iter = str;
        do
            this->push_back(*iter);
        while(*iter++);
    }

    c_string() {}

    //c_string(std::nullptr_t) {}

    char* data()
    {
        if(this->size())
            return &((*this)[0]); //line 26
        else
            return 0; 
    }

    const char* data() const { return this->data(); }

    operator char*() { return this->data(); }
    operator const char*() const { return this->data(); }

};

int main()
{
    c_string first("Hello world");
    c_string second(1024);

    printf("%s",first.data());
    printf("%c\n",first[0]);
    snprintf(second, second.size(), "%d %d %d", 5353, 22, 777);
    printf(second);
}
```

MinGW complains about:

```
D:\prog\PROJEKTYCPP\hehe_testc_cpp.cpp: In member function 'char* c_string::data()':

D:\prog\PROJEKTYCPP\hehe_testc_cpp.cpp:26:22: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]

In file included from d:\prog\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/vector:65:0,
                 from D:\prog\PROJEKTYCPP\hehe_testc_cpp.cpp:2:
d:\prog\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:768:7:note: candidate 1: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]:(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std:
:allocator<char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = char&; std::vector<_Tp,_Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]


D:\prog\PROJEKTYCPP\hehe_testc_cpp.cpp:26:22: note: candidate 2: operator[](char
*, int) <built-in>
```

How can I enforce calling correct overload? Can this problem hurt me silently?

Comment: Deriving from `std::vector` isn't a good idea. Its destructor isn't virtual.

Comment: So this means people won't be able to delete std::vector<char> pointer actually pointing to c_string, yes. Is composition better alternative?

Comment: no, it just means that they'll invoke undefined behavior if they do so. Which kind of undermines any claims of your class being easy to use.

Comment: Make your std::vector private base class. Or better private member variable. It is called composition. You probably do not want your c_string to be treated as simple vector - so hide/encapsulate this implementation detail of your c_String.

Comment: Unless you really need/want to allow converting your "string" to a `vector<char>`, it's probably easiest to use private inheritance.

Comment: You really should just use `std::string`. C++11 guarantees that `&s[0]` spits up a null-terminated modifiable string, and I suspect any implementation of `std::string` you're using probably supports it. Ensure you've verified you really cannot use your `std::string` implementation first.

Comment: don't cooperate with C functions expecting `char*`. They can break your code. You can cooperate with C functions expecting `const char*` and use a `std::string` (since C++11: get the `const char*` via `std::string::data()` or `std::string::c_str()`)

Comment: @GManNickG `std::string::data()` should not be used to write into (is UB), so how can `&s[0]` be okay? Isn't this the same pointer?

Comment: @Walter: It's the same location, different const-ness.

Comment: @Walter, the C++11 committee did a survey of its members and found all of them already used an implementation that was safe for `&s[0]`, so they put it into the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having an operator `char *` you've provided two ways to do `operator[]`. The first is `std::vector::operator[]` applied directly; the second is to convert `this` to `char*` and apply `[]` to that. In this case they both result in the same thing, but the compiler can't know that.

Resolve it by specifying explicitly which one you want.

```
        return &(operator[](0)); //line 26
```

or

```
        return &((char*)(*this)[0]); //line 26
```

Comment: Yeah, so the conversion operators were the problem after all ;] I removed them and code compiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the first warning, you can do this:

```
char* data()
{
    if(this->size())
        return &vector_char::operator[](0);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

To delete all warnings, remove the `operator char*()` and `operator const char*()` members.